# Fix border-radius from behaving inappropriately in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, border-radius

### Chrome

[image]

### Firefox

[image]

What can I do to alter my code so it has the Chrome appearance within Firefox? I'm using pseudo elements to mimic the appearance of overlapping table rows. If this look can be achieved without the use of pseudo elements that's also a solution that works for me.

```css
th:first-child, tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
th:last-child, tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody, tbody td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale( 1 );
  background-color: #333;
}
tbody td:first-child, tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody td:last-child, tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody::before, tbody::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  content: "";
}
tbody::after {
  top: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #444;
}
tfoot {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<style>
  html, table, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: #ddd;
  }
  html {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  table, th, td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  thead {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  th { text-transform: uppercase; }
  td { border-bottom: solid #222; }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th><p>one</p></th><th><p>two</p></th><th><p>three</p></th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td><p>four</p></td><td><p>five</p></td><td><p>six</p></td> </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr> <td><p>seven</p></td><td><p>eight</p></td><td><p>nine</p></td> </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually works fine. Just set `background:red` and see it.

```css
thead th:first-child, tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  background:red;
}
th:last-child, tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody, tbody td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale( 1 );
  background-color: #333;
}
tbody td:first-child, tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody td:last-child, tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
tbody::before, tbody::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  content: "";
}
tbody::after {
  top: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #444;
}
tfoot {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<style>
  html, table, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: #ddd;
  }
  html {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  table, th, td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  thead {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  th { text-transform: uppercase; }
  td { border-bottom: solid #222; }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th><p>one</p></th><th><p>two</p></th><th><p>three</p></th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td><p>four</p></td><td><p>five</p></td><td><p>six</p></td> </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr> <td><p>seven</p></td><td><p>eight</p></td><td><p>nine</p></td> </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

This happens because you set `thead { background-color: #222;}`. Use `th` instead of `thead`. See the snippet below.

```css
thead th:first-child,
tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}

th:last-child,
tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}

tbody,
tbody td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale( 1);
  background-color: #333;
}

tbody td:first-child,
tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}

tbody td:last-child,
tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}

tbody::before,
tbody::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  content: "";
}

tbody::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #444;
}

tfoot {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<style>
  html,
  table,
  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: #ddd;
  }
  
  html {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  
  table,
  th,
  td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #222;
  }
  
  th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  td {
    border-bottom: solid #222;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>one</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>two</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>three</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>four</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>five</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>six</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>seven</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>eight</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nine</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! it was the thead, tbody, tfoot etc being set opposed to the td,th that caused the problem as noted. This is perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Append these lines too in your code:-

```
border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 1.5rem;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
```

Do the same thing with the other radii.
The reason is Firefox, Internet explorer(before IE9), Safari don't support many CSS3 properties. You need to add the vendor prefixes(-moz, -webkit) to work with Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @dgknca Wherever there is a border radius property, you need to add the -moz-border-radius-xxxxxx property. Did you do that?

Comment: did you try your solution in firefox? they are very old prefixes. no need to use it anymore.